# there are two class A.class and B.class .....about pattern

Tags: java

A.class have a instance of B, which is b.  And in B , I want to use some method of A, can I have some method to make this simple?  case below.

```
class A{
   private B b = new B(this)

   public void anyMethod(){

   }
}



class B{
   private A mA;
   B(A a){
     mA = a;
   }

   public void someMethod(){
      mA.anyMethod();
   }
}
```

yes I was looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is--if you have an instance of A, you can call A's methods that you have access to.

Comment: Yes. It looks to me like you are implementing a simple composition strategy using dependency injection. Great practice for unit testing, among other things.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Is something not working?

Comment: I don't like this: `private B b = new B(this)`. One day, code like this might lead you to problems with threads... (the problem here is that a reference to an instance of A gets published (ie, passed to some other code) before the constructor finishes). And believe me, if you face the consequences of this potential visibility/reordering problem, you will never forget it.

Comment: I think he's asking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Also, *I want to use some method of A* sounds just like a bad excuse for a poor design. Looks like your are not with an Object Oriented mind set. Oh, and rigorously, `A.class` **does not** have an instance of B (when discussing code, you should be as precise as possible; one correct way to express what I believe you are thinking is: "an instance of A has an instance of B")

Comment: yes as bruno Reis said, this is what I was confusing.But I don't know other way to solve this problem.

Comment: @BrunoReis yes most time an instanc of A has an instance of B.

Comment: zyunchen, you should try to describe *what* you are trying to do, and not *how* you are trying to achieve it. Most probably there's a better way to do it, and it will be easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: well,I am now writing a interface of an android application.And there is a linearlayout, and in this layout there are three listviews, and when the focus changed in listviews or maybe press key center. linearlayout will handle these things. @Bruno Reis

Answer (score 0):

The code *is* valid in Java, and I agree with the comments - that `new B(this)` looks problematic. Moving that line to the constructor won't help much, since there's still a risk of B using a method in A before the A constructor ends.

I believe it's a better idea to separate the instantiation of B completely from the initialization process of A (that includes the constructor), and simply set it later with an init method, like this

```
class A {

    private B b;

    public A() {

    }

    public void initB() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

    public void anyMethod() {

    }

}
```

And later:

```
A a = new A();
a.initB();
```

Comment: note that the problem is not only that some code might use a method in A before the constructor finishes; **the problem is bigger and much more subtle**. The simply publication of A in the constructor might be problematic, and very strange things might happen if some code, in other thread, uses A after the constructor has finished.

Comment: @BrunoReis so Is there a better way? I do think this will lead many problems.

Comment: @zyunchen what problems do you think this approach will lead to?

Comment: @Óscar López I can not describe clearly, as my poor English. But somethings, instance of a has change something, but instance  of B doesn't  know. Or when instance of B want the width of layout A, but maybe at that time, A hasn't been on screen yet.it will suggest me with a nullpointer exception